# How to develop using SCA and OSGI on java eclipse

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, sca

I am trying to learn how to develop using Tuscany along with OSGi bundles to be used as the implementation of SCA components. I am using java on eclipse IDE. I tried to search for online tutorial to get started but I did not get anyone.

I found one link here http://tuscany.apache.org/sca-java-implementationosgi.html
which helps in the general idea, but it does not provide the details. I decided to try without tutorial, and I did something, but it did not work, and I got errors.

So here's what I did:
I created a bundle which contains the following interface:

```
package com.javaworld.sample.service;

import org.osoa.sca.annotations.Remotable;

@Remotable
public interface HelloService {
    public String sayHello();
}
```

The implementation of the interface works fine and I checked this project alone without Tuscany.

Now, here's the MANIFEST file of this bundle:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: HelloService
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.javaworld.sample.HelloService
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.javaworld.sample.service.impl.HelloServiceActivator
Bundle-Vendor: JAVAWORLD
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Export-Package: com.javaworld.sample.service
```

In a separate project, I have several components built as SCA, and this is my composite file called store.composite,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<composite xmlns="http://www.osoa.org/xmlns/sca/1.0"
    xmlns:t="http://tuscany.apache.org/xmlns/sca/1.0"
    xmlns:s="http://store" 
    targetNamespace="http://store" 
    name="store">

    <component name="store">
        <t:implementation.widget location="ufservices/store.html" />
        <service name="Widget">
            <t:binding.http uri="http://localhost:8080/store" />
        </service>
        <reference name="catalog" target="Catalog">
            <t:binding.jsonrpc />
        </reference>
        <reference name="shoppingCart" target="ShoppingCart/Cart">
            <t:binding.atom />
        </reference>
        <reference name="shoppingTotal" target="ShoppingCart/Total">
            <t:binding.jsonrpc />
        </reference>
       <reference name="hellowService" target="HelloWorldService">
            <t:binding.jsonrpc />
        </reference>
    </component>

    <component name="Catalog">
        <implementation.java class="services.CatalogImpl" />
        <property name="currencyCode">USD</property>
        <service name="Catalog">
            <t:binding.jsonrpc uri="http://localhost:8080/Catalog"/>
        </service>
        <reference name="currencyConverter" target="CurrencyConverter" />
    </component>

    <component name="ShoppingCart">
        <implementation.java class="services.ShoppingCartImpl" />
        <service name="Cart">
            <t:binding.atom uri="http://localhost:8080/ShoppingCart/Cart" />
        </service>
        <service name="Total">
            <t:binding.jsonrpc uri="http://localhost:8080/Total"/>
        </service>
    </component>

    <component name="CurrencyConverter">
        <implementation.java class="services.CurrencyConverterImpl" />
    </component>

    <component name="HelloWorldService">
        <implementation.osgi xmlns=http://tuscany.apache.org/xmlns/sca/1.0
             bundleSymbolicName="com.javaworld.sample.HelloService"                         
             bundleVersion="1.0.0.qualifier">
        </implementation.osgi>
      </component>
</composite>
```

You can see at the end of this file that I created a component which refers to osgi implementation of the HelloWorldService bundle.

Below is part of my store component which is an html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Store</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="store.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">

    //@Reference
    var hellowService= new tuscany.sca.Reference("hellowService");

    function displayHellowService()
    {
     var h= hellowService.sayHello();
    alert(h);

    }


</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Store</h1>
  <div id="store">

    <form name="shoppingCartForm">

        <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="displayHellowService()"/>
    </form>    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a launch java file which contains the main method and creates the whole thing.
Finally, below are the errors I get when i run the project.

```
SEVERE: ContributionReadException occured due to : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 51; columnNumber: 36; Open quote is expected for attribute "xmlns" associated with an  element type  "implementation.osgi".
يول 14, 2013 1:37:52 ص org.apache.tuscany.sca.assembly.xml.CompositeDocumentProcessor
SEVERE: ContributionReadException occured due to : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed
Exception in thread "main" org.osoa.sca.ServiceRuntimeException: org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.ContributionException: org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.ContributionReadException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.node.impl.NodeImpl.<init>(NodeImpl.java:204)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.node.impl.NodeFactoryImpl.createSCANodeFromClassLoader(NodeFactoryImpl.java:37)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.host.embedded.impl.DefaultSCADomain.init(DefaultSCADomain.java:178)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.host.embedded.impl.DefaultSCADomain.<init>(DefaultSCADomain.java:100)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.host.embedded.SCADomain.createNewInstance(SCADomain.java:182)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.host.embedded.SCADomain.newInstance(SCADomain.java:63)
    at launch.Launch.main(Launch.java:8)
Caused by: org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.ContributionException: org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.ContributionReadException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.impl.ContributionServiceImpl.addContribution(ContributionServiceImpl.java:421)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.impl.ContributionServiceImpl.contribute(ContributionServiceImpl.java:198)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.node.impl.NodeImpl.configureNode(NodeImpl.java:524)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.node.impl.NodeImpl.<init>(NodeImpl.java:200)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.ContributionReadException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.assembly.xml.CompositeDocumentProcessor.read(CompositeDocumentProcessor.java:214)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.assembly.xml.CompositeDocumentProcessor.read(CompositeDocumentProcessor.java:137)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.assembly.xml.CompositeDocumentProcessor.read(CompositeDocumentProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.processor.ExtensibleURLArtifactProcessor.read(ExtensibleURLArtifactProcessor.java:96)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.impl.ContributionServiceImpl.processReadPhase(ContributionServiceImpl.java:587)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.service.impl.ContributionServiceImpl.addContribution(ContributionServiceImpl.java:419)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:548)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:604)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:619)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:317)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.contribution.processor.DefaultValidatingXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(DefaultValidatingXMLInputFactory.java:226)
    at org.apache.tuscany.sca.assembly.xml.CompositeDocumentProcessor.read(CompositeDocumentProcessor.java:181)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.StreamBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(StreamBootstrapper.java:443)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.StreamBootstrapper.resolveStreamEncoding(StreamBootstrapper.java:267)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.StreamBootstrapper.bootstrapInput(StreamBootstrapper.java:131)
    at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:543)
    ... 19 more
```

Can someone give me a guide to a tutorial or help me to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have XML syntax errors here:

```
  <component name="HelloWorldService">
    <implementation.osgi xmlns=http://tuscany.apache.org/xmlns/sca/1.0
         bundleSymbolicName="com.javaworld.sample.HelloService"                         
         bundleVersion="1.0.0.qualifier">
    </implementation.osgi>
  </component>
```

I can't help you otherwise, but SEVERE: ContributionReadException occured due to : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 51; columnNumber: 36; Open quote is expected for attribute "xmlns" associated with an  element type  "implementation.osgi".

is just XML parsing issues. You can tell by the 'SAXParseException', SAX being Simple API for XML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are declaring a XML namespace without quotes, change it to:

```
<implementation.osgi xmlns="http://tuscany.apache.org/xmlns/sca/1.0" />
```

Note the namespace is enclosed with quotes (**""**)

Furthermore, let me point you to this tutorial. Even though it is meant for Rational Application Developer, the code will work as well

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/topic/com.ibm.sca.tools.doc/tutorials/osgi/sca_osgi_abstract.html

Hope this helps.